# Submitting merchant defined shipping options using Google Checkout direct submission

Tags: api, shopping-cart, google-checkout

Is it possible to set the shipping options in Google Checkout without using the server-server submission option?

I'm trying to keep this checkout process as simple as possible (mostly because I do not fully understand the server-server API section), and therefore I'm using the direct submission option in Google Checkout (details [here](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API.html#create_checkout_cart). scroll down past the code block). So, I'd like to just add the hidden input fields to designate how much shipping will cost, and send it along.

Is this possible?

[Shipping options documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API.html#shipping_xsd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, in fact, possible. Here's how I did it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.shipping-methods.flat-rate-shipping-1.name" value="Delivery"/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.shipping-methods.flat-rate-shipping-1.price" value="123.45"/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.shipping-methods.flat-rate-shipping-1.price.currency" value="USD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.shipping-methods.flat-rate-shipping-1.shipping-restrictions.allow-us-po-box" value="false"/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.shipping-methods.flat-rate-shipping-1.shipping-restrictions.allowed-areas.us-country-area-1.country-area" value="CONTINENTAL_48"/>
```

Tricky for sure, but it works.